# cannot catch Meteor.Error in client when error thrown from server side of meteor method

Tags: javascript, meteor, error-handling, callback, meteor-methods

I have a meteor call and meteor method. When I throw Meteor error then it is not caught inside meteor call's error but instead in response

Here is my meteor method

```
Meteor.call("updateFtIndex", id, $(`#idx-${id}`).val(), function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error: ', error.reason);
    }
    else {
        console.log('result', result);
    }
})
```

and here is my meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateFtIndex: function (_id, index) {
        try {
            let isIndexExists = Meteor.users.findOne({_id, "profile.featuredProviderIndex": index }, {fields: 
             {"profile.featuredProviderIndex": 1}});
            if(isIndexExists){
                console.log('isIndexExists: ', isIndexExists);
                throw new Meteor.Error( 400, "Sorted index already exist !!!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("else");
                return Meteor.users.update({_id}, { $set: { "profile.featuredProviderIndex": index } });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return error
        }
    }
})
```

And I get the thrown error inside result of meteor call
Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 2):

You are catching the throw and your catch is returning the error but the better way to return an error to the front is your change it to this:

```
    try {
        let isIndexExists = Meteor.users.findOne({_id, "profile.featuredProviderIndex": index }, {fields:  {"profile.featuredProviderIndex": 1}});
        if(isIndexExists){
            console.log('isIndexExists: ', isIndexExists);
            throw new Meteor.Error( 400, "Sorted index already exist !!!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("else");
            return Meteor.users.update({_id}, { $set: { "profile.featuredProviderIndex": index } });
        }

    } catch (e) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(400, e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Got the error in client side by throwing it

Answer (score 1):

You are returning error instead of throwing it from catch block.